# Regex split by same character within brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a like long string, like so:

```
(A) name1, name2, name3, name3 (B) name4, name5, name7 (via name7) ..... (AA) name47, name47 (via name 46) (BB) name48, name49
```

Currently I split by "(" but it picks up the via as new lines)

```
string[] lines = routesRaw.Split(new[] { "  (" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

How can I split the information within the first brackets only? There is no AB, AC, AD, etc. the characters are always the same within the brackets.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)(.*?)(?:\(([A-Z])\2*\)|\z)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList()`

Comment: I'll give it a go in the morning. I've notice there is a 2*, it can go upto things like MMMMM or even AAAAAA. Not sure if 2 will cover that but a 6 would?

Is there a way to keep the original (A) within the matches string?

Comment: I will post a test snippet once I have access to my desktop, I'm on a mobile now.

Comment: For those in the audience who, like me, don't understand what you are trying to do, please edit to show the desired result for your example. Do you wish to split on every `'('` that is followed by a string of capital letters, followed by `')'`? If so, that sentence pretty much describes a regex you could use. Hmmm. My guess appears to be inconsistent with the understanding of the problem that is reflected in other comments.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a *matching* approach here since the pattern you need will contain a capturing group in order to be able to match the same char 0 or more amount of times, and `Regex.Split` outputs all captured substrings together with non-matches.

I suggest

```
(?s)(.*?)(?:\(([A-Z])\2*\)|\z)
```

Grab all non-empty Group 1 values. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%5BA-Z%5D%29%5C2*%5C%29%7C%5Cz%29&i=%28A%29%20name1%2C%20name2%2C%20name3%2C%20name3%20%28B%29%20name4%2C%20name5%2C%20name7%20%28via%20name7%29%20.....%20%28AA%29%20name47%2C%20name47%20%28via%20name%2046%29%20%28BB%29%20name48%2C%20name49).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a dotall, `RegexOptions.Singleline` option that makes `.` match newlines, too
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars, but as few as possible
- `(?:\(([A-Z])\2*\)|\z)` - a non-capturing group that matches:

  - `\(([A-Z])\2*\)` - `(`, then Group 2 capturing any uppercase ASCII letter, then any 0 or more repetitions of this captured letter and then `)`
  - `|`  - or
  - `\z` - the very end of the string.

In C#, use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)(.*?)(?:\(([A-Z])\2*\)|\z)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
        .Where(z => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(z))
        .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/knmzBQ).